# Android emulator SDCard is removed for some reason

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard

I've created in the AVD a 3.2 (With Google APIs) device.
However, I lately can't seem to be able to use the SDCard, when using:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState();
```

I receive "removed".

How can I remount / unremove the SDCard?
(I've tried creating new devices, and restarting the device many times).

I'm working on Windows 7 with Eclipse 2010, if it matters.

Thanks,
Gal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MEMORY_CARD_SETTINGS);
startActivity(i);
```

and then mount sdcard from menu...

Comment: How do I mount the SD card from the menu?

Comment: Just Click on Mount SDCard , third item on list

Comment: I have no such thing at all - all I have is "stored on USB" with 20 megabytes written on it...

Comment: Go to eclipse>windows>Android SDK and AVD manager>Virtual Devices
, click on your virtual device and edit> set sd card

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this with....  The problem was fixed when I went into AVD / Android Virtual Device Manager and changed the SD card settings for the device.  I used the "create new image" button which I suppose creates a new file where the SD card contents are saved.